# How to move div randomly on load of the page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how I can move a div in a random direction on load of the webpage using java script.
I'am looking for something like how the enemies/ghosts move randomly in the pacman game.
how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var max_width = window.innerWidth;
  var max_height = window.innerHeight;
  
  var directions = {left:1,up:2,right:3,down:4}
  var direction = getRandomDirection();
  var distance = getRandomDistance();
  
  var target = document.getElementById("ghost");
  var target_pos = {top:0,left:0}
  
  var i = 0;
  
  var render_rate = 40;
  var move_step = 2;
  
  setInterval(function(){
      i++;
      if(i > distance){
         distance = getRandomDistance();
         direction = getRandomDirection();
         i = 0;
      }
      move(target,direction,move_step)
  },render_rate)
  
  function getRandomDistance(){
      return Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1) + 5;
  }
  
  function getRandomDirection(){
      return Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
  }
  
  function move(el,direction,step){
    switch(direction){
       case directions.left: {
         if(target_pos.left < max_width){
             target_pos.left += step;
             target.style.left = target_pos.left + "px";
         }
         break;
       }
       case directions.up: {
         if(target_pos.top < max_height){
             target_pos.top += step;
             target.style.top = target_pos.top + "px";
         }
         break;
       }
        
       case directions.right: {
         if(target_pos.left > 0){
            target_pos.left -= step;
            target.style.left = target_pos.left + "px";
         }
         break;
       }
        
       case directions.down: {
         if(target_pos.top > 0){
            target_pos.top -= step;
            target.style.top = target_pos.top + "px";
         }
         break;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#ghost{
  background-color:#def;
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="ghost"></div>
```

Comment: can you expalin these lines:

               function getRandomDistance(){
                return Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1) + 5;
                    }
  
                         function getRandomDirection(){
                        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

i mean why  * 20) + 1) + 5;
and * 4) + 1);

Comment: Yes sure have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp the more examples section. Basically Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1) will return a number between 1 and 20, but because distance of 1 wont be notice I am adding 5 so it ranges between 6 and 26. Direction is the same but generates a number between 1 and 4, because of the directions object.